# Why I can't find my database file in C: disc from DB Browser

Tags: sql, sqlite, file, db-browser-sqlite

I made database file called `doctors.db` in path given in following picture. I played with it in **Command Prompt** and it works perfect!
[image]

Now when I try to find it with program `DB Browser for sqlite`, you can see it is not possible to find it. Does someone know what the problem is? I am really surprised by this. I scrolled entire **PC folder** and still no sign of it..
[image]

Comment: Does the file have an extension and if yes, which one? (It seems like it hasn't one. You should make sure Explorer is set not to hide extensions to be sure.) If it hasn't then give it one of the listed ones in the drop down above the "Open" and "Cancel" buttons of the file open dialog or see if you can change the value of that drop down to something like "All files (*.*)" or similar.

Comment: That is true, thanks for tip. Can you tell me how did my command prompt work even thought I didn't have extension in `doctors`?

Comment: I don't know what commands you used. But they might be happy when they get a correct file. The dialog just *filters* the files that are displayed, that doesn't mean the GUI program cannot open files without extension. There's a good chance, if you either set the filter to "All ..." or manually enter the filename without extension (as long as the files still has no extension of course) your GUI program will also happily open that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you've called it 'doctors.db', not just 'doctors'? The file type 'file' suggests it doesn't have its extension.

Comment: Omg, I have been studying too much today. That was exact the reason WHY! I have just tested it and it works now.

Comment: But one question. How did my command prompt **statements** still work? I made `doctors` and not `doctors.db` and it still worked, hmmm?

Comment: To that question, I don't know. If you're tired you may have been in a different folder, or even c:\

Comment: No, no. I worked with that same file (no extension file). I wonder now how did it work..

Comment: Not 100% sure it matters anymore - can rack it up to 'dunno?'. But maybe after your work in command prompt, you copied or moved the file from one location to another, or renamed it, forgetting the '.db' thing at the end (e.g., `rename hospital.db doctors`)